# União de array multidimensional em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chamado_codigo] => 5
            [representante_id] => 1
            [data] => 2015-10-08
            [razaoSocial] => mineoro
            [cliente_cidade] => chapeco
            [tecnico_nome] => jacomasio
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chamado_codigo] => 6
            [representante_id] => 2
            [data] => 2015-10-08
            [razaoSocial] => mineoro
            [cliente_cidade] => chapeco
            [tecnico_nome] => Eduardo
        )

)
```

Quero unir o array abaixo com o acima:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valor] => R$ 0,45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valor] => R$ 0,50
        )

)
```

Ou seja, quero deixar assim, é possível? Como eu faço?

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [chamado_codigo] => 5
                [representante_id] => 1
                [data] => 2015-10-08
                [razaoSocial] => mineoro
                [cliente_cidade] => chapeco
                [tecnico_nome] => jacomasio
                [valor] => R$ 0,45
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [chamado_codigo] => 6
                [representante_id] => 2
                [data] => 2015-10-08
                [razaoSocial] => mineoro
                [cliente_cidade] => chapeco
                [tecnico_nome] => Eduardo
                [valor] => R$ 0,50
            )

    )
```

Comment: já tentou com `array_merge()` ? http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar assim (cosiderando `$a` o array original e `$b` o secundário):

```
$i=0;
$novoArray = array();
foreach($a as $valor) {
    $novoArray[] = array_merge($valor, $b[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Veja funcionando aqui: http://ideone.com/cLwZ2H

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente a função `array_merge_recursive` deveria fazer o trabalho.

No entanto, quando os índices não estão definidos ou são números, a função não funciona.

Na página do [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge-recursive.php) existe uma função que funcionou bem.

veja o exemplo:

```
function my_array_merge ($arr,$ins) {
  if(is_array($arr))
  {
    if(is_array($ins)) foreach($ins as $k=>$v)
    {
      if(isset($arr[$k])&&is_array($v)&&is_array($arr[$k]))
      {
        $arr[$k] = my_array_merge($arr[$k],$v);
      }
      else {
// This is the new loop :)
        while (isset($arr[$k]))
          $k++;
        $arr[$k] = $v;
      }
    }
  }
  elseif(!is_array($arr)&&(strlen($arr)==0||$arr==0))
  {
    $arr=$ins;
  }
  return($arr);
}

//aproveitando o exemplo do nosso amigo Jorge Campos
$a = array( array("chamado_codigo"=>5,"representante_id"=>1), array("chamado_codigo"=>6,"representante_id"=>2) );
$b = array( array("valor"=>"R$ 0,45"), array("valor"=>"R$ 0,50") );

print_r(my_array_merge($a,$b));
```

o que resultará em

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chamado_codigo] => 5
            [representante_id] => 1
            [valor] => R$ 0,45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chamado_codigo] => 6
            [representante_id] => 2
            [valor] => R$ 0,50
        )

)
```